# ids is empty in a python kivy boxlayout with children

Tags: python, kivy

I've created a Screen with a boxlayout and its children.
I wanna print size of the label "Hello" in the boxlayout, which has id:shadow_label
This size must be relative. But it's [100, 100]
Why?
What could I give more details for this post? Could this behavior be due to AnchorLayout?

Here is my code
kv file:

```
<WellcomeScreen>:
    box_layout: wellcome_box

    BoxLayout:
        id: wellcome_box
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos: self.parent.pos
        size: self.parent.size
        padding: [30, 30]
        spacing: 10
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'Data\game background.png'
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        Label:
            id:shadow_label
            size_hint: (1, .6)
            font_size: self.height/12
            text_size: self.width-10, None
            color: 'purple'
            halign: "center"
            text: "Hello"

        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint: (1,.3)
            Button:
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:
                        source: "Data\Button_start.png"
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

                pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
                size_hint: (None, None)
                size: (self.parent.height/4*3, self.parent.height/4*3)
                background_color: (1,1,1,0)
                font_size: self.height/4
                text_size: self.width, None
                text: "START"
                color: "yellow"
                bold: True
                halign: 'center'
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                    root.manager.current = 'login'
```

python

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '420')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '860')


class WellcomeScreen(Screen):
    user_name = ObjectProperty()
    box_layout = ObjectProperty()
    wellcome_label = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WellcomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class StartButton(ButtonBehavior, MDLabel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StartButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background_normal = "Data\Button_start.png"
        self.text = "START"
        self.text_color = "yellow"
        self.color = "white"
        self.halign = "center"


class FastReadApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        sm = ScreenManager()
        screen_wellcome = WellcomeScreen(name='wellcome')
        sm.add_widget(screen_wellcome)

        print(screen_wellcome.ids.shadow_label.size)

        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = FastReadApp()
    app.run()
```

There is the screen of my app:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the size of the label before its size is set, so you see the default size of `(100,100)`. Just delay the print until the size is set. Use `Clock.schedule_once()` or use a `Button` to trigger the print.